# Packaged REST API service

Tags: rest, service

I want to be able to package a REST API service that doesn't run or exist as a service until invoked. Think a DLL library that talks REST.

My requirements are:-

1. The package can be developed in any language but only communicates in REST.
2. The package does not run until invoked. i.e. It doesnt exists as a service or process anywhere waiting for requests.
3. It closes itself down at disposal. Think using() in C#
4. Its for low frequency calls so start up costs is negligible.

Is this a thing. I am trying to google it but I don't know how to describe it.

Comment: do you want somthing like `aws lambda` or `serverless`

Comment: @nay. I checked serverless, it didnt seem to be what i want. I specifically just want packages I can make REST requests on without having to setup any services or processes to host them. Where the packages are located is not material.

Comment: It seems there is no such thing.or I don't konw what you really want.or something like `docker`?you can write any language and package it.when you request you can run that docker up.but in fact.when you request,there must has a process to listen on some tcp port.